# Как написать функцию на js которая будет делать мульти выбор и отмену?

Tags: javascript

есть 3 блока просто div  надо чтоб пользователь мог их выбирать по одному или несколкьо сразу а при повторном нажатии отменить выбор , как реализовать такой функционал

Comment: Вроде как 3 тысячи репутации, а вопросы не умеете задавать) Покажите, как вы пытались решить проблему и в чем конкретно у вас возник вопрос

Comment: Оберните это все в `label` и установите чекбоксы, как-то так....,и ThisMan абсолютно прав

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего сложного:

1. Получить нужные дивы по классу
2. Каждому дать обработчик события клика
3. В обработчике переключать класс

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.item')

elements.forEach(i => {
  i.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
    if (!target.classList.contains('disabled'))
      target.classList.toggle('selected')
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.selected {
  border-color: blue !important;
}

.item {
  border: .4rem solid black;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  width: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">Машина</div>
<div class="item">Паравоз</div>
<div class="item">Самолет</div>
<div class="item disabled">Велосипед</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю вы сделали мой день!!!!!!!!

Comment: Илья а как сделать чтоб допустим  веооспиед нельзя было выбирать ?

Comment: сделать его как то дисабле